# Python - How to send an email with attachment without loading the whole file into memory at once?

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, smtplib

I would like to send emails with attachments of 10MB or more in a VPS with low RAM; the usual way to send an email with attachments in Python 3 (that I have found) is this:

```
from email.message import EmailMessage
# import other needed stuff here omitted for simplicity
attachment = 'some_file.tar'
msg = EmailMessage()
# set from, to, subject here
# set maintype, subtype here
with open(attachment, 'rb') as fd:
    msg.add_attachment(fd.read(),  # this is the problem, the whole file is loaded
                       maintype=maintype,
                       subtype=subtype,
                       filename=attachment)
# smtp_serv is an instance of smtplib.SMTP
smtp_serv.send_message(msg)
```

With this approach the whole file is loaded into memory and then the EmailMessage object is sent with smtplib.SMTP.send_message, what I am expecting is a way to give to add_attachment a file descriptor(or an iterable), instead of the file content, that is read in a lazy approach(ex. line by line or by some fixed amount of bytes) while the attachment is sent to the server, something like:

```
with open('somefile') as fd:
    msg.add_attachment(fd, maintype=mt, subtype=st, filename=fn)
    smtp_serv.send_message(msg)
```

Is there a way to do this(sending an attachment without loading the whole file at once) with the standard library (email and smtplib)???? 
I can't find any clue in the python documentation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The solution is to use [ContentManager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.contentmanager.html), [ContentManager.set_content()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.contentmanager.html#email.contentmanager.set_content) is the way _any_ data put into a message. The problem is that the standard ContentManager supports only a limited number of data types. So one need to extend it if he/she needs more

Comment: The question is 'do you _really_ need to put _that_ big files into attachments?' Have you considered possible problems with SMTP servers limitations and possible overflows of message recipients' mailboxes?

Comment: I really need to send these files through email, the server limit is 50 MB for one email and the mailbox's space isn't a problem and the emails will be downloaded while they arrive, anyway I don't think that loading the whole file into memory is a good approach and is freezing my VPS. Right now I am too busy to check ContentManager, but I will check it as soon as possible, if you are sure this is the solution post an answer with some code example and I will accept it, thanks!

Comment: Can you use an `mmap` object as a substitute for a string?

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to upload the attachments to an S3 bucket or Google Storage bucket, and then provide a URL in the email for the recipient to download it.   Most mail servers will restrict the size of the attachments, so they are very unlikely to get through to most mail clients.

You don't have to use a public bucket, you can obfuscate the attachment names, and add a "presigned" url - that only works for a finite amount of time:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/python-s3-generate_presigned_url.py.html

Comment: the use case was to receive the files as email attachments, because email server has free access or Intranet access while the rest of the Internet is restricted